# How to get row number of the selected cell after on the edit switch in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Actually I am creating a list in which there is a edit switch which is toggle able. But now I am wanting that if I on the switch then click any cell then it will display that cells row number. I tried this but it shows the cell address which was active before on the switch. But I want that user will on the switch then which cell will be clicked that cells row number will be in the msgbox.

Here is my tried code -

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()


If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
Else
    Exit Sub
End If


End Sub
```

Kindly help!

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Please read it again and try to edit grammar, e.g. verbs are often missing. Maybe some screenshot could also help.

Comment: Replace your code with this `MsgBox "The active cell row is " & ActiveCell.Row`  ,, will return Active cell's Row number !!

Comment: I think I didn't able to make understand you. I want that if I open the switch then click on a cell then a msgbox will appear in which it will display the row number of that cell which I clicked. If any question kindly ask.

Comment: What should happen after you press ok? Should the switch turn off or stay on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add worksheet_event code.

You can add that below your button code.

Eg: in the same worksheet code module:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then MsgBox Target.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Oooooopsss!! It was so simple. Thanks. Thanks. Thanks a lot bro. My brain was out of control. How simple an trick didn't thought. Really helped bro!